# How to split a Play application into several parts

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm trying to split my Play application into several modules as described in the  [Official Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTSubProjects)... but I'm wondering if there is a complete example... or a more comprehensive tutorial. Any help would be really appreciated :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate where exactly you are stuck? For me, the crucial point was understanding that in a project with sub-projects, you only have one `Build.scala` file (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project, "You cannot have a project subdirectory or project/*.scala files in the sub-projects").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look on the command line, in your root project directory start play, type `projects` and you'll see the splitted projects.

The one currently active for play is the one with the asterisk. You can switch projects with `porject yourProjectName`.

You could visualize the example in the documentation 'Splitting your web application into several parts' as followed:
[image]

I'd say if you navigate with play to main you can start both: website and admin.